# How can I change the name of file in the child's directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, mv

There is a child directory who name is stored in a variable called `temp`.
I'd like to rename all files in that directory to their lower case version.

So I wrote this code:

```
mv ls $temp 'ls $temp | tr [:upper:][:lower:] [:lower:][:upper:]'
```

but it doesn't work. How can I change it?

Comment: When I use double quotes like this // mv ls $dir "ls $dir | tr [:upper:][:lower:] [:lower:][:upper:]";//         There is an error    //                            mv: target 'ls temp3 | tr [:upper:][:lower:] [:lower:][:upper:]' is not a directory//

Comment: Does your directory contain a `$` in its name, literally?

Comment: I contain directory name in variable $temp. So there is ./temp in variable $temp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop.

You can use [Bash brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to convert to lower case, instead of `tr` which creates an extra process each time:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$temp"
for f in *; do
  mv "$f" "${f,,}"
done
```

If you want to reverse the case of each character of the file name (thanks @SLePort for the tip):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$temp"
for f in *; do
  mv "$f" "${f~~}"
done
```

Comment: Nice one... I totally forgot we can use that `^` operator.

Comment: mv: cannot move './temp/koPmQwe' to './TEMP/KOpMqWE': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move './temp/NkeDasWdq' to './TEMP/nKEdASwDQ': No such file or directory//////////// this error came out when I use latter code.

Comment: Try `mv "$f" "${f~~}"` to reverse the case.